# Redirects to default.aspx instead of "xxx.aspx" after logging into app using login control

Tags: asp.net, security, redirect

Thanks for going to answer my question. I have the folowing pages.

- login.aspx
- default.aspx
- xxx.aspx

After logging into application default.aspx will be displayed. Now if the user is trying to open http://server/**xxx.aspx**?Id=1234 by specifying its URL directly in a browser, the login screen is displayed and after successfull login, system redirects to "default.aspx" and not to "http://server/**xxx.aspx**?Id=1234". Actually there is an external application that would call my system like that. So Please let me know why is this happening. The .Net login control is used to login into the application. Kindly help me to solve this issue.

Thanks,
Ang Vin

Comment: Could you post what you have in your "loggedin" Routine and/or any authentication you have in your web.config?

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Forms Authentication or doing this directly in the application?  If you do something like this in your web.config it will handle all the redirecting for you.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
            <forms name="FwLoginCookie" loginUrl="Login.aspx"
        protection="All" 
        path="/" >
            </forms>
        </authentication>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
```

Is there anything in the URL stating the ReturnURL?  With the above setting if the user tries to go to xxx.aspx I would expect the URL of the login dialog to look like "Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=xxx.aspx"

Answer (score 1):

Check that you are NOT setting the DestinationPageUrl property in the login control:

```
<asp:Login 
  ID="Login1" 
  runat="server" 
  DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx">
</asp:Login>
```

I assume you have as this property overrides the default behaviour you are actually looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```